# Save ints in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-sharedpreferences

I'm new to programming and I need to save more than 1 ints in SharedPreferences. I'm making a counter and I want to just save values of all ints in my code. How would I do that? If possible, can you modify my code with Shared Preferences.
Thanks

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int i=0;
int j=0;
int k=0;

TextView x= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
TextView y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
TextView z = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            i++;
            x.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    });


    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            j++;
            y.setText(String.valueOf(j));
        }
    });

    Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            k++;
            z.setText(String.valueOf(k));
        }
    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
private static void setInt(Context context, String name, int i) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(name, i);
    editor.apply();
}

private static int getInt(Context context, String name, int default) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getInt(name, default);
}
```

Comment: where would I place it and how can it save all 3 ints?

Comment: Just make those two methods part of your MainActivity.

From your MainActivity you could call setInt(this, "k", k); or k = getInt("k", -1);

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried to do it but couldn't get it to work. Can you edit my code please so I can where it should be? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@DroidGalaxy In SharedPreferences you can save at a time one value. In order to use shared preferences , you have to call a method getSharedPreferences() that returns a SharedPreference instance pointing to the file that contains the values of preferences. 
Here instance pointing means it can retrieve last value that can save in this.
For example-

```
             if you can store in your int varaiable = 10, then in next time you get value int varaiable = 10 .
```

but in next time -

If you change int varaiable = 10 TO int varaiable  =  20 then it can return int varaiable = 20.